# Sistema de gestión de archivos

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

tengo un pequeño detalle, verán este es un sistema para crear carpetas y subir archivos, simple, hace todo bien, lo único que quiero ahora es que diferencia los archivos que sube y que por defecto los nombre dependiendo por el input que entren

Este es el modal por donde entran los archivos

```
`<div id="modalArchivos" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="my-modal-title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="title-carpeta"> Selecciona una opción para agregar: </h5>

             
                <button class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body" >
            <div class="search">
                <form>
                    <input class="form-control" id="inputBusqueda" type="text" placeholder="Buscar..." aria-label="Search">
                    <div id="container-result"></div>
                </form>
                <a href="#" class="toggle-search"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
            </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="id_carpeta">
                <div class="d-grid">

                    <button type="button" id="btnSubirArchivo1" name="CedFun" class="btn btn-outline-info m-r-xs"> <i class="material-icons">add</i>Cédula</button>
                    <hr>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSubirArchivo2" name="pdf" class="btn btn-outline-info m-r-xs"> <i class="material-icons">add</i>Partida de nacimiento</button>
                    <hr>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSubirArchivo3" name="rif"    class="btn btn-outline-info m-r-xs"> <i class="material-icons">add</i>Rif</button>
                    <hr>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSubirArchivo4" class="btn btn-outline-info m-r-xs"> <i class="material-icons">add</i>Prueba psicológica</button>
                    <hr>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSubirArchivo5" class="btn btn-outline-info m-r-xs"> <i class="material-icons">add</i>Documentos Familiares</button>
                    <hr>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSubirArchivo6" class="btn btn-outline-info m-r-xs"> <i class="material-icons">add</i>Servicio Militar</button>
                    <hr>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSubirArchivo7" class="btn btn-outline-info m-r-xs"> <i class="material-icons">add</i>Documentos de Ingreso</button>
                    <hr>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSubirArchivo8" class="btn btn-outline-info m-r-xs"> <i class="material-icons">add</i>Situaciones Administrativas</button>
                    <hr>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSubirArchivo9" class="btn btn-outline-info m-r-xs"> <i class="material-icons">add</i>Régimen Disciplinario</button>
                    <hr>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSubirArchivo10" class="btn btn-outline-info m-r-xs"> <i class="material-icons">add</i>Régimen de Seguridad Social</button>
               

                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

la función Javascript que los envía

```
 file.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
     console.log(e.target.files[0]);
     const data = new FormData();
     data.append('id_carpeta', id_carpeta.value);
     data.append('file', e.target.files[0]);
     const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
     const url = base_url + 'admin/subirarchivo';
     http.open("POST", url, true);
     http.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
         let porcentaje = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
         container_progress.innerHTML = `<div class="progress">
         <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: ${porcentaje.toFixed(0)}%;" aria-valuenow="${porcentaje.toFixed(0)}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">${porcentaje.toFixed(0)}%</div>
     </div>`;
     })
     http.addEventListener('load', function () {
         setTimeout(() => {
             window.location.reload();
         }, 1500);
     })
     http.send(data);
     http.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             console.log(this.responseText);
             const res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
             alertaPerzonalizada(res.tipo, res.mensaje);
         }

     };
 })

 carpetas.forEach(carpeta => {
     carpeta.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
         id_carpeta.value = e.target.id;
         myModal2.show();
     })
 });
```

el código php que la clase y la función que los envía

```
     public function subirarchivo()
    {
        $id_carpeta = (empty($_POST['id_carpeta'])) ? 1 : $_POST['id_carpeta'];
        $archivo = $_FILES['file'];
        $name = $archivo['name'];
        $tmp = $archivo['tmp_name'];
        $tipo = $archivo['type'];
       


            if ($tmp = 'pdf') {
                $data = $this->model->subirPartida($name, $tipo, $id_carpeta, $this->id_usuario);

            } elseif ($tmp = 'rif') {
                $data = $this->model->subirarchivo($name, $tipo, $id_carpeta, $this->id_usuario);
            }


        if ($data > 0) {
            $destino = 'Assets/archivos';
            if (!file_exists($destino)) {
                mkdir($destino);
            }

            $carpeta = $destino . '/' . $id_carpeta;
            
            if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
                mkdir($carpeta);
            }

            move_uploaded_file($tmp, $carpeta . '/' . $name);
            $res = array('tipo' => 'success', 'mensaje' => 'ARCHIVO SUBIDO');
        } else {
            $res = array('tipo' => 'error', 'mensaje' => 'ERROR SUBIR ARCHIVO');
        }
        echo json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        die();

    }
```

y el código php que los inserta en la base de datos

```
    public function subirArchivo($name, $tipo, $id_carpeta, $id_usuario)
    {
        
        $name = "CED".$name;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO archivos (nombre, tipo, id_carpeta, id_usuario) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        $datos = array($name, $tipo, $id_carpeta, $id_usuario);

        

        return $this->insertar($sql,$datos);

   
    }

    public function subirPartida($name, $tipo, $id_carpeta, $id_usuario)
    {
        
        $name = "PDN_FUN".$name;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO archivos (nombre, tipo, id_carpeta, id_usuario) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        $datos = array($name, $tipo, $id_carpeta, $id_usuario);

        

        return $this->insertar($sql,$datos);

   
    }
```

He estado probando con condicionales en las clases y en el javascript pero creo que no lo estoy haciendo bien, lo que quiero es que dependiendo de por qué input entren los archivos, se guarden con diferentes nombres, hasta ahora guarda pero solo pasa por el primer caso ignorando la condicional y le pone el mismo nombre a todos los archivos, si pueden ayudarme lo agradecería mucho